# C++, the loop is somehow not ending

Tags: c++, loops

i'm making small program about polynomials, and have a one problem. When im putting string, to get coefficients and deegres from it, it's processing only the first monomial and then the loop infinitely processing the rest of polynomial.

For example i put the string "5x^3+2x^2+x+1" , it's processing 5x^3 and then infinetely displaying 2x^2+x+1. I know there's some problem with the loop.
The code i wrote:

```
void Wielomian::analiza(Wielomian *w, char * napis) {
do
{
    AnalizaJ(w, napis);
}
while (*napis);
}

void Wielomian::AnalizaJ(Wielomian *w, char * napis) {
int pom1,potega;
    if(*napis=='x')
    {
        pom1=1;
    }
    else
    {
        pom1=strtol(napis,&napis,10);
        napis++;
    }
    if(*napis=='^')
    {
        napis++;
        potega=strtol(napis,&napis,10);
    }
    w->wsp[potega]=pom1;
    napis++;
    printf("%s",napis);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Fyi, `napis++;` means *nothing* to the *caller* of your function, that seems to expect it to transition to the terminator. Running this in a *debugger* and single stepping each iteration, you'll see that the address in `napis` never changes. This is a very, *very* common question with many duplicates on this site, but most of them are so utterly divergent in their titles and descriptions they're often non-trivial to find.

Comment: The quickest fix is to pass in a reference to `napis`: `void Wielomian::AnalizaJ(Wielomian *w, char & * napis)`. The problem is that as it stands, the changes made to `napis` in `AnalizaJ` are never passed back to the caller. BTW, I'd choose the signature of `char *Wielomian::AnalizaJ(Wielomian *w, char const * napis)` and `return napis;` at the end of the function.

Comment: incrementing `napis` in `AnalizaJ` does not affect `napis` in `analiza`

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, now get it all, cheers ! :)

Comment: You indeed call by value "a pointer", so that the replica pointer does not affect the original pointer at caller side.